# Resistance with kitchen sink tube extension

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

[image]

I have the pictured sink and every time we pull it down there is a large amount of resistance. It also appears the inside tubing is starting to fray indicating it’s rubbing against something. I looked below the sink and don’t see anything that would obstruct the path. Has anyone encountered this or have any suggestions? I’ve tried googling and YouTube but can’t find any similar issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to look under the sink. There should be a plastic bushing at the end of the spout under the sink. The bushing is to prevent the hose from abrading on the metal edge.

The bushing could be cracked, or missing.  There could be other items under the sink interfering with the spray hose, or the weight.